# Searching in a CSV file - python

Tags: python, csv, search

I have a csv file containing a lot of songs. Each row has 5 columns, which are:

Artist | Song Title | Album Name | Genre | Year

I would like to open a CSV file, and then search all the song names to bring up results. Therefore, if I search for 'heaven', I would want one of the results to turn up as "Stairway to **Heaven** by Led Zeppelin". I am unaware of how to specify specific columns of CSV file when performing a search, and returning the results.

I am still new to python so a simple answer would be best, if possible

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried anything so far? if so please share the code

Comment: Take a look at the `csv` module.

Comment: Consider using Logstash/ElasticSearch to store your songs.  It does really fast text searching across multiple data elements.  And you can use Python as an interface to it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: The search is only in one column or in all?

Comment: The csv module converts the file to a list of rows, where each row is a list of columns. You search this list-of-lists for the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

To search for songs, you can use this:

```
import sys
import csv

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'Please provide a song name to search for.'
    sys.exit(-1)

match = None
with open('songs.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    next(r, None) # skip header
    for row in r:
        if sys.argv[1] in row[1]:
            match = row[:]
            break

if match:
    print '%s by %s' % (match[1].strip(), match[0].strip())
else:
    print '%s not found.' % (sys.argv[1])
```

Call it like this:

```
python search.py Heaven
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of a file named **songs.csv**

```
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """
Artist;Song Title;Album Name;Genre;Year
Rush;Tom Sawyer;Moving Pictures;Progressive Rock;1981
Led Zeppelin;Black Dog;Led Zeppelin IV;Hard Rock;1970
AC/DC;Back in Black;Back in Black;Hard Rock; 1980
"""
songs_file = StringIO(s)
```

Load data file into a [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

```
from csv import DictReader

songsdb = [i for i in DictReader(songs_file, delimiter=';')]

def search(criteria):
    for row in songsdb:
        for data in row.values():
            if criteria in data:
                print row

search('Black')

{'Album Name': 'Led Zeppelin IV', 'Genre': 'Hard Rock', 'Year': '1970', 'Song Title': 'Black Dog', 'Artist': 'Led Zeppelin'}
{'Album Name': 'Back in Black', 'Genre': 'Hard Rock', 'Year': ' 1980', 'Song Title': 'Back in Black', 'Artist': 'AC/DC'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin said in his comment, you'll want to use the `csv` module for this one.

[Here are some examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) for how to use it.

If you want to be able to specify names of columns (and not just their positions), you'll want to take a look at [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), which works just like the `csv.reader` used in the examples from my first link, but with dicts (mappings of column names to column values) rather than lists of the column values in order.